# ggpaired: Dataframe replacement has different number of rows

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have a dataframe (growth_data) containing BMI-z-scores for different subject_IDs for several visits. I want to compare BMI z-scores between visit 0 and 4 and plot this with the ggpaired function.

First, I subset only visit 0 and visit 4 for each subject_ID.

```
growth_data_selected <- subset(growth_data, visit == 0 | visit == 4, select = c("subject_id", "visit", "bmi_z_score"))
```

Second, I want to plot this data using the ggpaired function.

```
ggpaired(growth_data_selected, x = "visit", y = "bmi_z_score",
         color = "visit", line.color = "gray", line.size = 0.4,
         palette = "jco")
```

However, R returns an error message:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "id", value = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L,  :
> replacement has 1176 rows, data has 1177

Does anyone know what the problem is and how to fix this?

Comment: Have a look at ```growth_data_selected```. There seems to be some data missing resulting in unequal lengths of vectors to be used in ```ggpairs()```. Maybe missing data?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?